# PHP Exceptions, Errors and Giving User Feedback

Tags: php, error-handling, exception

This is the situation. Let's say I have a form that collects a first name, last name and email address, all fields being required.

Typically I'd just check a field, if it's not set then echo an error. That's good and all but I want to handle things more elegantly. I've been reading about throw / try / catch and I understand how to make these work, but I'm not sure when I should be using these.

Let me be a little more specific about what I want to do.

So again I have 3 fields:

- First name
- Last name
- Email

I take these fields and run them through a validator. The validator returns an array with the field as the key and an error message (if there is one). I'd like to loop through the array and somehow set these errors to some sort of global error array. This array will be read by a controller that will prepare the errors for display. Make sense?

I assumed throw / catch / try could do this but I can only throw 1 error at a time. What I'd like to do is display all errors to the user at once.

I realize I could be way off base here but that's why I'm asking for advice. In this situation what is the best practice?

Comment: "I take these fields...Make sense?" - That entire paragraph completely makes sense. Why not write the code and try it out?

Answer (score 0):

One (possibly slightly extreme) rule of thumb I've seen is that you should only use Exceptions where you would be happy with the program exiting. This is partlbecause if you don't catch the exception, that's what will happen; but it also highlights the idea that exceptions should not be used for "business as usual", flow control, situations.

As you've discovered, as soon as you throw an exception, you are blasted out of whatever you were doing, so you can't create multiple exceptions at the same time. So your best bet for validation is simply to build up an array of errors - it doesn't need to be global, just return it from a validate method, or as a member of a Validator object.

What happens to the messages next depends partly on personal style, and partly on the structure of your code. You might want to just pass them straight to a template, proceeding only if there are none to display. But you might find this requires checking in multiple places for "returned error, don't proceed", in which case throwing a single exception with the messages wrapped in it might make more sense, since you know that no code between there and the catch will run.